# CSS/JS - Opening Fan Effect

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I am trying to replicate the effect of a fan opening with css. I have managed to achieve this for one 'panel' by using `transform-origin` and `transform: rotate()` however am struggling to get a third 'panel' to work. The code I have written so far is below:

See how the orange element is in alignment with the blue, the red should behave in the same way (in relation to orange).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
}

.right {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50vw;
  background: blue;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.middle {
  position: fixed;
  background: orange;
  width: 25vw;
  right: 50vw;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.left {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 25vw;
  left: 0;
  top: 10%;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="fan">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your .left class to the following:

```
position: fixed;
background: red;
width: 25vw;
top: 10%;
transform-origin: top right;
transform: rotate(-20deg);
right: 75vw;
```

Comment: Thanks - I did try this but it still leaves a gap - see here: https://imgur.com/a/CMg6Z3J